How to convert a row number to a cell number (ie. Row Number = 2, so Cell Number = A2)
I am trying to have a program that takes information from a separate excel form and deposit that information into the next empty row.
I have a line of code that selects the next empty row, but now I need that row to be converted into a cell. I have tried
Sheet1.range("A" + unusedRow).CopyFromRecordset rs

and it gives me an error "Type mismatch".
Any help would be appreciated.
Option Explicit

Sub GetDataFromClosedFile()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim file As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Dim GetFile As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim unusedRow As Long
    
    'Determines the next empty row
    unusedRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row
    
    'Allows you to select which file to pull information from
    Set file = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With file
        .Title = "Select a File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        '.InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = sItem
    Set file = Nothing

    Sheet1.range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Clear

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & GetFile & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No';"

    cn.Open
    
        'Selects which cell in the file to copy
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
        rs.ActiveConnection = cn
        rs.Source = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:A2]"
        rs.Open
    
        'Selects which cell in the mastersheet to copy info into
        Sheet1.range("A" + unusedRow).CopyFromRecordset rs
       
        rs.Close

    cn.Close
    
End Sub


Change the + to &.

Or use Sheet1.Cells(unusedRow,1)
